# Combine three different Aggregate into a single one

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have three different Aggregations that I would like to combine to one.

```
objsCount = self.db.bidding.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$bid_item",
      "number_of_objects": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])

objsPrice = self.db.bidding.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"$and" : [{"price": {"$ne":"null"}},{"users":{"$ne":"null"}}]}},
  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$bid_item",
      "total_price": { "$sum": '$price' },
      "total_users": { "$sum": '$users' }
  }}
])

objsHigestBid = self.db.bidding.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"$and" : [{"highestBid": {"$ne":"null"}},{"users":{"$ne":"null"}}]}},
  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$bid_item",
      "total_number_of_users_after_bid": { "$sum": '$highestBid' }
  }}
])
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
 [{ _id : '',
  number_of_objects : '',
  total_price : '', 
  total_users : '', 
  total_number_of_users_after_bid : ''
 },...]
```

How could I change my "aggregates" to one single "aggregate" that make this possible?

Comment: Do you want to `$match`  in your first query?

Comment: ...will your second query return the expected result if "highestBid" not null? will your last query work if "price" is not null?

Comment: Very good questions @user3100115. "Do you want to $match in your first query?" - No, "..will your second query return the expected result if "highestBid" not null? will your last query work if "price" is not null?" - Yes and Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a single **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline, you can take advantage of the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator in the pipeline step to evaluate the counts based on the logic specified, something like the following:

```
db.bidding.aggregate([    
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$bid_item",             
            "number_of_objects": { "$sum": 1 },
            "total_price": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$ne": [ "$price", "null" ] }, "$price", 0 ]
                }
            },
            "total_users": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$ne": [ "$users", "null" ] }, "$users", 0 ]
                }
            },
            "total_number_of_users_after_bid": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$ne": [ "$highestBid", "null" ] },
                                { "$ne": [ "$users", "null" ] }
                            ]
                        },
                        "$highestBid", 0 
                    ]
                }
            } 
        }  
    }
])
```